# Kotlin Kapt doesn't show databinding errors when running from Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm using Kotlin kapt version 3, whenever there is a problem with databinding, the build from Android Studio fails with a very generic error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDev21DebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

When I run the same task from the console, the real problem shows up. Somehow the AS doesn't show this error in message window.

I'm using Android Studio version 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You can see the error in **Gradle Console**, something similar to this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Android Studio 3.0` and later version of android studio support `Kotlin` better. `AS 3.0` comes with default support with Kotlin as `AS 2.3` requires a plugin to be installed.

`Android Studio Team` from google and `IDEA intellij` Team from JetBrain working together to make Kotlin compatible with `Android Studio`.

Right now 3.0 version comes with Canary version(Preview version) and every week a new preview version (Canary 1, Canary 2 ... and so on) rolls out fixing reported bugs.

So you should try Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9 latest version as of now.

If still problem persists, report this bug.

Comment: the same issue on AS 3.0 Canary 9

Comment: You can raising an issue if you think its really a bug.